# show different path with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, path, directory

On my webserver I would like to keep the following folder structure, so that it's easier to maintain:

`/de/index.html`

How do I change the visible URL in the webbrowser **www.mydomain.de/de/index.html** to **www.mydomain.de/index.html** via .htaccess?

I would like to keep the /de/ directory on the server, but I don't want to display it in the browser.
What would you advise?

Answer (score 2):

This is a trivial rewrite.

This version assumes that your script, image, and CSS files still use the /de/whatever.css structure in your markup.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Don't rewrite requests to /de or other real files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/(css|scripts)
# Rewrite incoming requests to their equivalent behind /de
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ de/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And this version allows the images, CSS, and scripts to have their /de hidden as well:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Don't rewrite requests to /de or other real files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/de/?
# Rewrite incoming requests to their equivalent behind /de
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ de/$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### Update

To force redirection of requests to /de to use the new URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Force redirection out of /de
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/de/
RewriteRule test/de/(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/test/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]

# Don't rewrite requests to /de or other real files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/(css|scripts)
# Rewrite incoming requests to their equivalent behind /de
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ de/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I will try this asap. Does the .htaccess still have to be in the main directory or do I have to move it to /de?

Comment: The .htaccess file should be placed in the main directory, above /de.

Comment: I used the first version and kept the images, css, etc. all in their directories (e.g.: .../de/css/all.css), and the html-part get's displayed, but it seems the scripts, css and images get the wrong path. Does it matter that the path is currently www.domain.de/test/de?

Comment: @BlueHorizon And you currently have the .htaccess inside the `/test` directory?

Comment: Yes, the .htaccess sits currently inside the `/test` directory.

Comment: @BlueHorizon Your scripts & css are currently in which path, /test/de or /de?

Comment: The scripts & css are in `/test/css` or `/test/scripts`.

Comment: @BlueHorizon Not sure why they're not getting the right path. See the additional `RewriteCond` line I added above, which should not be necessary.  Also check in your server logs to see what paths are being requested for those files when they error with 404.

Comment: If I change the path of the css,etc. to `css/all.css` (was `../css/all.css` before) the stuff loads when calling `domain.de/test/index.html`. But I can still also access `domain.de/test/de/index.html`. How do I redirect this adress to  `domain.de/test/index.html`?

Comment: @BlueHorizon Try out the part updated above.  Then when it works properly, remove the `test/` from both lines

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your effort ;)! I copied your update and pasted it into the `.htaccess` (residing in `domain.de/test/`). Alas the redirection is not working :(.